# Что означает @ в php?

Tags: php

Увидел вот такую строку.

```
$data['searchResult']= @$res;
```

`$res` это массив. А что означает знак `@` перед массивом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ - подавляет вывод ошибки функции, в данном случае - массива

Answer (score 3):

Из документации:

> PHP поддерживает один оператор управления ошибками: знак (@). В
>   случае, если он предшествует какому-либо выражению в PHP-коде, любые
>   сообщения об ошибках, генерируемые этим выражением, будут
>   проигнорированы.

http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: Добавлю только, что не рекомендуется, все же, этим пользоваться. Потому, что лучше отловить все ошибки в коде и их исправить, нежели подавить. Иначе это может все плачевно закончится.